# Using algorithms from OMPL in ROS navigation stack

Tags: navigation, ros, ompl

I would like to know if there is a way to use the sampling algorithms from OMPL in the ROS navigation stack. I'm aware of adding various algorithms as plugins for the navigation stack. Unfortunately, I cant write my own, and many sampling algorithms aren't available online.

any help is appreciated, 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [MoveIt](https://moveit.ros.org/documentation/planners/)? It includes support for the OMPL. What navigation stack are you using that you can't write your own planners?

Comment: i cant write my own because my CPP knowledge is limited(working on it) and I don't have time.